Looking for help in sonarqube api
used the curl command to get coverage measure data for a particular project.  Sample code below
curl -i GET --url "www.sonarcubeserver.com/sonar/api/measures/component?component=testproject&metric=coverage" --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx'



ooking for the response output, see that it's html with text saying 'loading'
 <span aria-live="polite" class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span>

200 is http response of curl.
expecting the actual metric
json format

 "measures": [
      {
        "metric": "complexity",
        "value": "12"
      },

